Sending email with ACTION_SENDTO recently stopped working
I am using Intent.ACTION_SENDTO to send an email to a specific email address in my Android App. The code below has been in production for roughly 5 years, and I never had a problem with it. It did as expected - populating the to field, subject field, and body of email.
fun sendEmail() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:")

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, arrayOf<String>("myemail@email.com"))
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email Subject here")

    val emailString = "<b>Email Message here</b>"

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailString,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY))
    } else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(emailString))
    }

    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}

As of the past couple of weeks, I am getting reports from multiple users that the email button stopped working - and pressing it simply does not do anything.
Reproducing the error:
I am able to reproduce the error on the emulator in Android Studio. intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) is returning null, so startActivity(intent) is not evaluating.
If I remove the if statement, and call startActivity(intent) directly, the App (in emulator) opens the pre-packaged Gmail App. This is bad practice though, and I don't want to cause crashes in production if the user does not have an email App.
My presumption is there was a recent Android update that is causing intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) to return null?
How can I resolve this issue so that the email button works as intended?
EDIT: I can now reproduce this problem on my Android tablet that runs Android 14, however on my Android phone which runs Android 9, the button works as intended.

Use ACTION_SEND instead.

No effect. Still behaves the same as ACTION_SENDTO

Just use startActivity() and catch the exception when activity not found.

intent.data = Uri.parse("mailto:") Try without.

"My presumption is there was a recent Android update that is causing intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) to return null?" -- I wouldn't describe it as "recent", but have you addressed package visibility?

@CommonsWare I have not, but I am now able to confirm this problem is happening on Android 14. On Android 9, the button works as intended.

Personally, I would remove resolveActivity() and use try/catch instead, as shown in the duplicate. In theory you can use <queries> to advertise your package visibility requirements, though I have not tried that for a mailto: ACTION_SENDTO Intent.
